# Why is index not created after teardown if some connections persist?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I setup and teardown my MongoDB database during functional test.

One of my models will make use of GridFS and I am going to run that test (which also calls setup and teardown). Suppose we started out with a clean empty database called `test_repoapi`:

1. `python serve.py testing.ini`
2. `nosetests -a 'write-file'`

The second time I run the test, I am getting this:

```
OperationFailure: command SON([('filemd5', ObjectId('518ec7d84b8aa41dec957d3c')), ('root', u'fs')]) failed: need an index on { files_id : 1 , n : 1 }
```

If we look at client:

```
> use test_repoapi
switched to db test_repoapi
> show collections
fs.chunks
system.indexes
users
```

Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/1adX4svG

There are three kinds of timestamps:

(1) the top one is when I first launched the web app

(2) anything before `23:06:27` were the first iteration

(3) then everything else were the second iteration

As you can see I did initialized commands to drop the database. Two possible explanations:

(1) Web app holds two active connections to the database, and

(2) Some kind of "lock" prevents the index from fully created. Also look `fs.files` was not recreated.

The workaround is to stop the web app, start again, and run the test; then the error will not appear.

By the way, I am using Mongoengine as my ODM in my web app.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What version of mongoengine?  And can you provide a test case?  Pymongo does cache ensure_index results.

Answer (score 0):

We used to have similar issue with mongoengine failing to recreate indexes after `drop_collection()` during tests because it failed to realise dropping collection also drops the indexes. But that was happening with normal collections and a rather ancient version of mongoengine (and a call to `QuerySet._reset_already_indexed()` fixed it for us - but we haven't needed that since 0.6)

Maybe this is another case of mongoengine internally keeping track of which indexes have been created and it's just failing to realize the database/collection vanished and those indexes must be recreated? FWIW using `drop_collection()` between tests is working for us and that includes GridFS.